# How to receive an email with Wordpress?

Tags: email

I would like to receive datas from an external client to a Wordpress website. Example: I send an email to someone and I would like to send a copy (to archive it) to the website/smtp server.

Is there an easy solution in?

Email send to `example@example.com` copy to `website@wordpress.com`

Comment: To clarify, you're not interested in sending emails *from* WordPress, you want to receive emails *at* WordPress? Like, check your email from the admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

By default, WordPress is not equipped to be an email server. It can ***send*** email but does not ***receive*** email.

If you want to ***send*** mail to multiple recipients then [`wp_mail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) will allow you to specify multiple addresses.

```
<?php

$multiple_recipients = array(
    'example@example.com',
    'website@wordpress.com'
);
$subj = 'The email subject';
$body = 'This is the body of the email';

wp_mail( $multiple_recipients, $subj, $body );
```

But if you want to check your email through the admin panel then you really need a plugin to ***read*** email from an external source -- not specific to WordPress.

Comment: Do you know about any plugin that I can use to archive emails on a Wordpress website? in other words, a plugin that will answer the question? (I looked around but had no luck) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The WP plugin Postie offers an email client in WordPress with IMAP or POP3

https://wordpress.org/plugins/postie/

Answer (score -2):

Hope the below mentioned plugin will help you :

[WP Easy SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/)

Then you will need to configure the SMTP settings with it.

Comment: This is only sending from wordpress, not receiving